# Spark DataFrame equivalent to Pandas Dataframe `.iloc()` method?

Tags: pandas, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to reference Spark DataFrame columns by position using an integer?

Analogous Pandas DataFrame operation:

```
df.iloc[:0] # Give me all the rows at column position 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, but you can try something like this:

**Python**:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo", 2.0)]).toDF()
df.select(*df.columns[:1])  # I assume [:1] is what you really want
## DataFrame[_1: bigint]
```

or

```
df.select(df.columns[1:3])
## DataFrame[_2: string, _3: double]
```

**Scala**

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "foo", 2.0))).toDF()
df.select(df.columns.slice(0, 1).map(col(_)): _*)
```

**Note**:

Spark SQL doesn't support and it is unlikely to ever support row indexing so it is not possible to index across row dimension.

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent of Python `df.iloc` is collect

**PySpark examples:**

```
X = df.collect()[0]['age']
```

or

```
X = df.collect()[0][1]  #row 0 col 1
```

Comment: collect() can quickly result in memory errors on large dataframes as it retrieves all the elements of the dataset (from all nodes) to the driver node, as such should only be used on small datasets.

Comment: For anyone who wants to know what to use instead of `collect()`, one can use `take()`

Comment: but `take()` gives you just a list as a result while with `iloc` in Pandas you can get a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in spark-shell.

```
scala>: df.columns  
Array[String] = Array(age, name)

scala>: df.select(df.columns(0)).show()
+----+
| age|
+----+
|null|
|  30|
|  19|
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 3.1.1 on Databricks, it's a matter of selecting the column of interest, and applying limit:

```py
%python
retDF = (inputDF
    .select(col(inputDF
        .columns[0]))
    .limit(100)
)
```