# How to process pyspark dataframe columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark df with >4k columns without any labels/headers. Based on the column values I need apply specific operations on each columns.

I did the same using pandas but I don't want to use pandas and would like to apply the column wise transformation directly on spark dataframe. 
any idea as how can i apply column wise transformation if  the df is having >4k columns without any label.also I don't want to apply transformations on specific df column index.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spark documentation, a dataframe contains - unlike what you said - headers, much like a database table.

In any case, a simple `for` loop should do the trick:

```
for column in spark_dataframe.columns:
    (do whatever you want to do with your columns)
```

Comment: ok, suppose when I loop over each column I do a regex check on column values and If it matches then i want to update it. in pandas i am doing something like df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0]) . how can i do in spark df

Comment: @occasionalvisitor never used iloc before. check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487170/spark-dataframe-equivalent-to-pandas-dataframe-iloc-method)